# Android connection Refused on Python Web Service

Tags: python, json, web-services, bottle

Im working on a Android app that connects to a web service written in python (Bottle Framework). I've tested the python service and works fine, but when i try to connect it through android it gives me an connection refused error.

Ok, this is the process i've made:

1. Coded the Python Web Service on Bottle Framework.

   - I have just a function that adds a product to a MySQL database.
   - This returns a JSON response.
   - Tested locally and works fine.
2. Coded the Android app with a JSONParser (to parse the JSON from the Python code)

   - JSONParser class execute HttpPost object, with the Bottle URL. Example: (http://'localhost':8080/add_product) - (http://'myMachineIP':8080/add_product), both local ip addresses.
   - Then my problem is here, when i send the data from the android app to bottle, on the Logcat i see an connection to http://'localhost':8080/add_product or http://'myMachineIP':8080/add_product refused.

I made a project like this, but in PHP, and it works fine. Im thinking the Bottle server dont allows me to do POST operations, but how to solve it?

I hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: `localhost` is your Android device if it is the client. Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you sure the IP provided,is accessible from android device??